# Can't add rows from array of dictionaries to a NSTable programmatically

Tags: swift, cocoa, row, nstableview

I would like to be able to programmatically add rows to my Table.
It was easy enough to add column headers from an array.
I have an array of dictionaries containing the row data
I'm able import the csv data into this array.

```
var rowData = [[String:String]]()
```

I want to dump this into my table's rows.
What am I missing?

I've tried... func numberOfRows() and func tableView() but they have no effect like they do when I create a table with IB

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

class TableView:NSObject{

    var tableContainer = NSScrollView.init(frame: NSRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 200))
    var tableView:NSTableView = NSTableView(frame: NSRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 200))

    func populateHeaders(){
        for x in 0..<headers.count {
            let column = NSTableColumn.init(identifier:NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: headers[x]))
            tableView.addTableColumn(column)
            column.headerCell = NSTableHeaderCell(textCell: headers[x])
            }
        }





    override init (){
        super.init()
        populateHeaders()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()
        tableContainer.documentView = tableView
        tableContainer.hasVerticalScroller = true

    }

}

extension TableView: NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return csvArray.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        var result:NSTableCellView
        result = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: (tableColumn?.identifier)!, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        result.textField?.stringValue = csvArray[row][(tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue)!]!
        print("hi")
        return result
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool {
        return true
    }


}
```

No Errors, the above code runs.  Just need a way to import rows.

Comment: You are not using `NSTableView`'s `DataSource` delegate method to show table rows.

Comment: Not sure what you mean?
I've tried this 
`func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        var result:NSTableCellView
        result = tableViewView.makeView(withIdentifier: (tableColumn?.identifier)!, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        result.textField?.stringValue = csvArray[row][(tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue)!]!
        return result
    }` 
It's not populating the rows!

Comment: `func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?` for what!?  cell-based or view-based table view cell?

Comment: Cell-Based
I'm using a submit button on my ViewController to update the data could this be an issue...
`@IBAction func submitBtn(_ sender: NSButton) {
        importBtnObj.isHidden = false
        csv.csvToList()
        self.view.addSubview(TableView().tableContainer)
        submitBtnObj.isHidden = true
        TableView().tableView.reloadData()
    }`. Also, I've updated the code above...  Still can't get the rows to populate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a wrong table view DataSource delegate method.  Use the `tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:)` delegate method for the cell-based table.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
    let dict = csvArray[row]
    if ((tableColumn?.identifier)!.rawValue == "firstColumn") {
        return dict["whatever"]
    }
    else if ((tableColumn?.identifier)!.rawValue == "secondColumn") {
        return dict["whatever"]
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

I don't know the exact column ID.  Enter an ID for each column under the identity inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Special Thanks to El Tomato,
I still have a ton of things to learn but the code below works!
I'm now able to import any old CSV with headers into a TableView and display it in the View Controller...

I tweeked El Tomato's answer like this...

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        let dict = csvArray[row]
        print(dict[headers[1]])
        for x in 0..<headers.count {
            if ((tableColumn?.identifier)!.rawValue == headers[x]) {
                print(dict[headers[x]])
                return dict[headers[x]]
            }
        }
        return "nil"   
    }
```

I was originally creating a class. Since I barley understand wtf I'm doing I put everything into the ViewController.swift.  I can try refactoring now that I've got it figured out.  Working Code Below!

```
import Cocoa

var csvArray = [[String:String]]()
var headers = [String]()
var globalPathToCsv:NSURL!
var csv = CSVaccessability()

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
    var tableContainer = NSScrollView.init(frame: NSRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 200))
    var tableView:NSTableView = NSTableView(frame: NSRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 200))
    func populateHeaders(){
        for x in 0..<headers.count {
            let column = NSTableColumn.init(identifier:NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: headers[x]))
            tableView.addTableColumn(column)
            column.headerCell = NSTableHeaderCell(textCell: headers[x])
        }
    }

    func setup (){
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()
        tableContainer.documentView = tableView
        tableContainer.hasVerticalScroller = true
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var submitBtnObj: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var importBtnObj: NSButton!
    @IBAction func submitBtn(_ sender: NSButton) {
        importBtnObj.isHidden = false
        csv.csvToList()
        self.view.addSubview(tableContainer)
        submitBtnObj.isHidden = true
        setup()
        populateHeaders()

    }

    @IBAction func importBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
        openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
        openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["csv"]
        openPanel.begin { (result) in
            if result == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK {
                globalPathToCsv = openPanel.url! as NSURL
            }}
submitBtnObj.isHidden = false
importBtnObj.isHidden = true
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        submitBtnObj.isHidden = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return csvArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        let dict = csvArray[row]
        print(dict[headers[1]])
        for x in 0..<headers.count {
            if ((tableColumn?.identifier)!.rawValue == headers[x]) {
                print(dict[headers[x]])
                return dict[headers[x]]

            }
        }
        return "nil"

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```